# Differentiation of derivative of left / right translation for tangent vector

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group, X be a tangent vector on $x \in G$ ( $X \in T \_x G$ ), and $\phi$ be an one-parameter subgroup on $G$.

I want to calculate these 2 formula;
$$
\frac{d}{dt} d L_{\phi} X
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dt} d R_{\phi} X
$$
where $L$ and $R$ are left translation and right translation $G \rightarrow G$.

Some books describe $d L_{\phi} X$ as $\phi X$ and $d R_{\phi} X$ as $X \phi$, and calculate them;
$$
\frac{d}{dt} d L_{\phi} X = \frac{d}{dt} \phi X = \frac{d \phi}{dt} X
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dt} d R_{\phi} X = \frac{d}{dt} X \phi = X \frac{d \phi}{dt}
$$
They look strange for me. How can those calculation be justified and how can I calculate them "formally"?

Comment: You just did. What are you asking?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Those solutions look a sort of Leibniz rule. But those "product" are actually function application. I could not sure whether the rule can apply to this problem. So I want to see more explicit calculations.

Comment: If you understand the language, try a simple matrix example.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you for the last half sentence. I will try.